# Expect timeout, in Bash scripting

Tags: bash, expect

How do I add timeout for "expect" in the following script? I want to set it as 120 seconds.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST="localhost"
USER="myuname"
PASS="mypassword"

VAR=$(expect -c "
spawn ssh $USER@$HOST
expect \"password:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect \"\\\\$\"
send \"ls\r\"
expect -re \"$USER.*\"
send \"logout\"
")

echo "==============="
echo "$VAR"
```

Answer (score 15):

The default timeout for `expect` is 10 seconds according to its manpage.  To change it to 120 seconds, before `spawn ssh $USER@$HOST`, add the line

```
set timeout 120
```

to make this

```
VAR=$(expect -c "
set timeout 120
spawn ssh $USER@$HOST
expect \"password:\"
send \"$PASS\r\"
expect \"\\\\$\"
send \"ls\r\"
expect -re \"$USER.*\"
send \"logout\"
")
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the following extract of the man page for expect:

"
expect [[-opts] pat1 body1] ... [-opts] patn [bodyn]

waits until one of the patterns matches the output of a spawned process, a specified time period has passed, or  an end-of-file is seen.  If the final body is empty, it may be omitted.

Patterns  from  the most recent expect_before command are implicitly used before any other patterns.  Patterns from the most recent expect_after command are implicitly used after any other patterns.

If the arguments to the entire expect statement require more than one line, all the arguments may be "braced"  into one  so  as  to  avoid  terminating each line with a backslash.  In this one case, the usual Tcl substitutions will occur despite the braces.

If a pattern is the keyword eof, the corresponding body is executed upon end-of-file.  If a pattern is the  keyword timeout,  the  corresponding body is executed upon timeout.  If no timeout keyword is used, an implicit null action is executed upon timeout.  The default timeout period is 10 seconds but may be set, for example to 30, by the  command  "set  timeout  30".   An  infinite  timeout  may  be designated by the value -1.  If a pattern is the keyword default, the corresponding body is executed upon either timeout or end-of-file.

If a pattern matches, then the corresponding body is executed.  expect returns the result of the body (or the empty string  if  no  pattern  matched).   In  the event that multiple patterns match, the one appearing first is used to select a body.
...
"

Answer (score 1):

[@DerfK has answered your question](https://serverfault.com/a/290136/515968).  I'd refactor your script for maintenance though:

```
#!/bin/bash
export HOST="localhost"
export USER="myuname"
export PASS="mypassword"

script=<<'END_OF_SCRIPT'
    set timeout 120
    spawn ssh $env(USER)@$env(HOST)
    expect "password:"
    send "$env(PASS)\r"
    expect "\$"
    send "ls\r"
    expect -re "$env(USER).*"
    send "logout"
    expect eof
END_OF_SCRIPT

VAR=$(expect -c "$script")

echo "==============="
echo "$VAR"
```